# How to merge two dataset with unequal rows depending on dummy value in R

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have two R dataframe with unequal rows that need to be merged based on value of the dummy in a column.

```
x <- c(3,4,5,3,5,1,4,5)
y <- c(0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0)
df1 <- data.frame(x,y)

  x y
1 3 0
2 4 0
3 5 1
4 3 0
5 5 1
6 1 1
7 4 0

z <- c(7,8,9)
y <- c(1,1,1)
df2 <- data.frame(a,b)

  z y
1 7 1
2 8 1
3 9 1
```

Is it possible to merge it the two such that the resulting dataframe is the following without the use of a loop?

```
  x y z
1 3 0 0
2 4 0 0
3 5 1 7
4 3 0 0
5 5 1 8
6 1 1 9
7 4 0 0
```

When the first value 1 appears in y, the value of z is set to the first value of z in df2.

Answer (score 0):

You may try

```
library(dplyr)

df1 <-df1 %>%
  group_by(y) %>%
  mutate(n = 1:n())

df2 <- df2 %>%
  group_by(y) %>%
  mutate(n = 1:n())
df1 %>%
  left_join(df2, by =c("n", "y")) %>%
  mutate(z = replace_na(z, 0)) %>%
  select(-n)
  
      x     y     z
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     3     0     0
2     4     0     0
3     5     1     7
4     3     0     0
5     5     1     8
6     1     1     9
7     4     0     0
8     5     0     0
```